# Printing out a char[]

Tags: c

I cannot for the life of me remember how to do this. This program opens a file then reads the file. All I would like it to do is print out the contents it has just read.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   char memory[1000]; //declare memory buffer size
   int fd = 0;
   int count = 1000;


   if ((fd = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY)) == -1)
   {
      fprintf(stderr, "Cannot open.\n");
      exit(1);
   }

   read(fd, memory, count);

   //printf the buffered memory contents

   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`printf` accepts `%s` format to print a C-string. However, by default it requires that string to have a [null-terminator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null-terminated_string) (0x0 ASCII code). If you are sure it was read by the call to `read` then you can do this:

```
printf("%s\n", memory);
```

However, you cannot be sure. Because you don't even check how many bytes were read... or for error code.
So you have to fix your code first.

Once you are done checking for errors and know how many bytes were read, you can do this:

```
printf("%.*s\n", (int)bytes_that_were_read, memory);
```

Good luck!

Comment: Is it not `printf("%.*s\n")` ?

Comment: @hmjd: Right. Corrected. Thank you!

Comment: @nos: Right, but "%.*s" format does the job no matter what is in that string as long as you have the correct number of bytes.

Comment: Keep in mind that `printf()` use with `"%.*s\n"` will stop for a non-terminated string, but if there are '\0' characters in the buffer, the `printf()` will also stop at that point (which may or may not be what you want).

Answer (score 1):

```
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
  printf("%c", memory[i]);
}
```

Comment: why "unsigned" int though?

Answer (score 1):

1. Set the last char to `\0` in memory
2. use printf()

Or read one character less because last one you will need to set as `\0`

Answer (score 1):

Do you have to stick to `printf()` for some reason? What if the file is binary with `'\0'` somewhere inside? This will break even `printf("%.*s", ...)`. If you read with `read()` you should be able to write with `write()`:

```
while (bytes_written < bytes_read)
{
    ssize_t x = write(STDOUT_FILENO,
                      memory + bytes_written,
                      bytes_read - bytes_written);
    if  (-1 == x) 
    {
        exit(1);
    }
    bytes_written += x;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a for loop and `printf("%c", buffer[i])` to print one char at a time or you can use `printf("%s", buffer)` if the buffer is a null-terminated string.